# Sharepoint Client run time dll not recognized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to develop Sharepoint CSOM to fetch data from Sharepoint online.
As i do not have the sharePoint setup on my machine, i have just copied the SharePoint client and SharePoint client Runtime dll's on to my machine and the same i have added under reference. The dll version is 15. But when i include the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime namespace, it is not getting recognized. Am using Visual studio 2013 and i checked for the Framework version 4.5,4 and 3.5. Please suggest what could be the error.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the *.dll*s from the server may work, but it would be better to download and use the official [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585).

There is no such namespace as `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` at all. The namespaces included in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` assembly are:

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Application
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Mime

As far as I see there are only internal classes in the later two namespaces. Most of the time you need only the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namespace.